# Querying solr in a loop returns nothing

Tags: java, solr, solrj, querying

I am very new to Solr and trying to implement a java program that queries solr every 30 seconds.

Scenario:

1. When the program starts up, it queries solr to retrieve DDI network activities during the previous 1 month.
   Following is the query.
   query.set("q","pname:'Deep Discovery Inspector' AND eventName:MALWARE_DETECTION AND logTime:[NOW-1MONTH TO NOW] AND app:HTTP");
   query.setRows(10000);
2. After this initialization, the program queries DDA every 30 seconds.
   Following is the query.
   query.set("q","pname:'Deep Discovery Inspector' AND eventName:MALWARE_DETECTION AND logTime:[NOW-30SECOND TO NOW] AND app:HTTP"); 
   query.setRows(10000);

query in #1 returns some results.
But the second query, which is called every 30 seconds does not return anything. SolrDocumentList.size() is 0 ALWAYS.

following is my java code.

```
 public void run(){
    Connection conn;
    PreparedStatement ps;

    int dda_count = glob_var.dda_cnt;

    long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    System.out.println("Solr handling thread started... Thread ID: " + threadId);

    System.out.println("Solr monitoring started... Thread ID: " + threadId);

    while(true){
        try{
            for(int j = 0; j < glob_var.dda_cnt; j++){
                Query_DDA_Solr(dda_solr[j], my_url);
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }

            Thread.sleep(30000);

        } catch(Exception e){
            log.write_log("DDIC_SOLR_CON/run: " + e);
        }
    }
}

public static void Query_DDA_Solr(String dda_s, String my_u){

try{
    Connection conn;
    PreparedStatement ps;

    SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(dda_s);          
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();

    //query.set("q","pname:'Deep Discovery Inspector' AND eventName:MALWARE_DETECTION AND logTime:[NOW-5MINUTE TO NOW] AND app:HTTP"); 
    query.set("q","pname:'Deep Discovery Inspector' AND eventName:MALWARE_DETECTION AND app:HTTP"); 
    query.setRows(10000);
    QueryResponse rsp = server.query(query);
    SolrDocumentList results = rsp.getResults();

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(my_u, glob_var.my_userid, glob_var.my_userpw);
            System.out.println("size of result = " + results.size());                   
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
        //boolean insert = false;
        String virusname = "", request = "";
        Timestamp etime = null;

        String element = results.get(i).toString();
        StringTokenizer ts = new StringTokenizer(element, "{");
        ts.nextElement();
        String ts2 = ts.nextElement().toString();
        ts = new StringTokenizer(ts2, ",");

        while(ts.hasMoreTokens()){
            String pair = ts.nextToken();
            StringTokenizer ts_2 = new StringTokenizer(pair, "=");
            String temp_attr = ts_2.nextElement().toString();

            if(temp_attr.equals(" logTime")){
                String eventtime = ts_2.nextElement().toString();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
                Date d = (Date) sdf.parse(eventtime);
                Timestamp temp_ts = new Timestamp(d.getTime());
                etime = temp_ts;

                break;
            }
        }   

        String app = "";

        // other works here

        //if(insert){
        if(etime.after(glob_var.solr_timestamp)){
            ResultSet trs = null;
            PreparedStatement my_ps;

            // database insert here
        }
    }

    conn.close();
    results.clear();
    query.clear();
    server.shutdown();

    Thread.sleep(5);

} catch(Exception e){
        log.write_log("SOLR_CON/Query_DDA_Solr: " + e);
}

}
```

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong in this code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Increase the query.setRows(xxxx) to some big number and check, it helped me